# Decode array of 2 elements passed to a function using pointer in c

Tags: c

I want to implement a function where we pass an array of 2 elements.
But while getting actual values I'm getting only one element of array. How to get the second element also?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

uint16_t a;
uint8_t arr[2];

void mcp_write(uint8_t reg, uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t length)
{
    uint16_t buff;

    printf("%d\n",reg);
    printf("%d\n",*buffer);
    printf("%d\n",length);
}

int main()
{
    arr[0]=15;
    arr[1]=255;
    mcp_write(1,arr,1);

    getch();
}
```

Output is

```
1
255
1
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n",buffer[0]); printf("%d\n",buffer[1]);` and instead of hard coding a length of 1 you probably want `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`

Comment: Your output doesn't match your code. And you only print the first element of the array with `printf("%d\n",*buffer);` (which BTW is equivalent to `printf("%d\n", buffer[0]);`, so what do you expect?

Comment: It would seem that you should print the array from a loop based on the `length` argument.

Comment: @kaylum. That just solved my problem. I cannot upvote bcz I'm new here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
void mcp_write(uint8_t reg, uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        printf("%d\n",reg);
        printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);
        printf("%d\n",length);
    }
}

int main()
{
    arr[0]=15;
    arr[1]=255;
    mcp_write(1,arr,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    getch();
}
```